# empty xml element stops code generation

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to create a list that will be held in xml file. Basically it will be a person's name and a description; the extra info is not a mandatory field, and when it is empty, I don't want to display a line for it. So I have a script:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","data/names.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("position");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    document.write("<p class='text' style='font-size:");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("size")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("px'>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("person")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</p>");
    if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("info")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue!=""){
        document.write("<p class='text' style='font-size:");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("info_size")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("px'>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("info")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</p>");
    }
}
```

So my way of thinking:

1. It writes down persons name with specified size,
2. Checks if extra info is not empty,
3. If it's not empty, write second line with extra info in specified size,
4. If empty, do nothing and repeat with next item.

The problem is that when it reaches the empty element, it stops. It won't display further positions. If it is not empty, everything is working fine.

Here is sample of testing xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <position>
        <person>Empire Burlesque</person>
        <size>10</size>
        <info>USA</info>
        <info_size>17</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>Hide your heart</person>
        <size>11</size>
        <info>UK</info>
        <info_size>16</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>Greatest Hits</person>
        <size>12</size>
        <info>USA</info>
        <info_size>15</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>Still got the blues</person>
        <size>13</size>
        <info>UK</info>
        <info_size>14</info_size>
    </position>
        <person>test</person>
        <size>17</size>
        <info></info>
        <info_size>10</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>tests</person>
        <size>17</size>
        <info></info>
        <info_size>10</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>testa</person>
        <size>17</size>
        <info></info>
        <info_size>10</info_size>
    </position>
    <position>
        <person>testb</person>
        <size>17</size>
        <info></info>
        <info_size>10</info_size>
    </position>
</root>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT to display your XML data more directly?

Comment: It is my frist try at XML and have not tried XSLT. I see it would be easier to use it, but can I use XSLT for style arguments?